# Is Change Feed available for Tables in Cosmos DB

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) for change feed, and downloaded the Table API, but cannot find any feed support for tables...
Am I missing something or is change feed only available for documents and the document API ?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of change feed is exposed through the DocumentDB API. The Cosmos DB team is currently investigating how to best enable change feed to users across all the APIs. Please help us prioritize this work on the Cosmos DB feedback forums here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db